# ¿Cómo usar Ajax para ejecutar evento según estado de checkbox?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, css3

Estoy haciendo una interfaz para controlar un `Arduino` por medio del puerto serial.

Todo va muy bien, excepto que al pulsar el `checkbox` la página se recarga y eso hace que el `checkbox` pierda su estado de `checked`.

Estuve buscando por ahí como solucionar ese problema usando `Ajax`, para que la pagina no se recargue y se envíe sólo el ($_GET['submitOff/ON']): al php.... ayudaa ya me rindo. NO LO LOGRO :(

```js
<input type='checkbox' name='submitOn' id="submitOn" value='LED ON' onclick="submit();">
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir también el código `javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debe quedar similar a este:

```
$("#myCheckbox").on('click', function () { //Asignamos un evento clic al checkbox
        let ischecked = $(this).is(":checked"); //Verificamos que esté chequeado
        if (ischecked) {
            $.ajax({ //Realizamos el get a la URL que necesitamos
                type: "get",
                url: "submitOff/ON.php",
                success: function (msg) { //Imprimimos la respuesta de la petición
                  console.log(msg);
                }
            })
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Tienes que asignarle un evento `click`  a tu `checkbox` mediante javascript
- Luego dentro de la función que se le pasa como parámetro al evento puedes crear un **ajax** que haga una petición enviándole contenido lo que tu deseas ya sea por **url** o por **post**
- Luego el archivo php al cual haces la petición que se encontrará alojado en tus archivo y que este te devuelva lo que deseas o lo que hayas escrito en tu **archivo php**
- Luego mediante el mismo **ajax** recuperas el mensaje y lo utilizas como desees así logras lo que deseas sin recargar la página

> importante si dices que al darle `click` a tu `checkbox` se carga la página entonces  estas asiendo un evento `submit` por lo cual deberías asignar `preventDefault()`